# Loop through a string array in laravel

Tags: laravel, loops

I'm trying to loop through a a string and get array of records where the service status is equals to complete or cancelled. I'm having an issue of get all the records instead it response with the last record from the list.

My Controller:

```
        $id = $request->user_id;
        $history = bookings::select('*')->whereIn('service_status', ['complete', 'cancelled'])->where(['specialist_id'=>$id])->orderBy('time', 'DESC')->get();

        if($history->isempty()){
            return response()->json(['statusCode'=>'5', 'statusMessage' => 'Empty Record', 'data' =>[]]);
        }else{
            for($i = 0; $i < count($history); $i++){
                $b_id = $history[$i]->id;
                $service = $history[$i]->service;
                $time = $history[$i]->time;
                $date = $history[$i]->date;
                $location = $history[$i]->location;
                $payment = $history[$i]->payment_type;
                $price = $history[$i]->amount;
                $special_request = $history[$i]->special_request;
                $s_id = $history[$i]->costumer_id;
            }
            $user = User::with('profile')->find($s_id);

            $data = array(['id'=>$b_id, 'date'=>$date, 'name'=>$user->name." ".$user->profile->lastname, 'speccial_request'=>$special_request, 'item'=>$service, 'time'=>$time." - 1 hour", 'location'=>$location, 'total'=>"$price"]);

            return response()->json(['statusCode'=>'0', 'statusMessage' => 'Successful','data' => $data], 200);
        }
```

My response is as follows:

```
{
    "statusCode": "0",
    "statusMessage": "Successful",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "date": "2020-07-08",
            "name": "User1",
            "speccial_request": null,
            "item": "Service",
            "time": "10:00 - 1 hour",
            "location": "street, city",
            "total": "300"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all the items from the DB not just one.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is there a reason your aren't using `Eloquent` queries or `Collection`s? They are one of the most powerful aspects of the Laravel framework and would make this task much more straight forward!

Comment: the name that i want to display belongs to another user. trying to create a history function

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an empty array (`$data`) and push to that array in each iteration.
Try below code:

```
$id = $request->user_id;
$history = bookings::select('*')->whereIn('service_status', ['complete', 'cancelled'])->where(['specialist_id'=>$id])->orderBy('time', 'DESC')->get();

if($history->isempty()){
    return response()->json(['statusCode'=>'5', 'statusMessage' => 'Empty Record', 'data' =>[]]);
}else{
    $data=[];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($history); $i++){
        $b_id = $history[$i]->id;
        $service = $history[$i]->service;
        $time = $history[$i]->time;
        $date = $history[$i]->date;
        $location = $history[$i]->location;
        $payment = $history[$i]->payment_type;
        $price = $history[$i]->amount;
        $special_request = $history[$i]->special_request;
        $s_id = $history[$i]->costumer_id;
        $user = User::with('profile')->find($s_id);

        array_push($data,['id'=>$b_id, 'date'=>$date, 'name'=>$user->name." ".$user->profile->lastname, 'speccial_request'=>$special_request, 'item'=>$service, 'time'=>$time." - 1 hour", 'location'=>$location, 'total'=>"$price"]);
        }
    return response()->json(['statusCode'=>'0', 'statusMessage' => 'Successful','data' => $data], 200);
}
```